# Should I ask to have a frozen chat room unfrozen or start a new chat room with the same or similar name?

Tags: support, chat

A chat room that I wanted to post more information in has been frozen for inactivity:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76868/free-will-omnipotence-determinism

Should I start another chat room with the same name or somehow ask that this old room be unfrozen?  If I should ask, what is the procedure for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defrosted the room. That's preferable, because like that you can keep history and favourite rooms.

The procedure is: ask one of the moderators on chat or meta to defrost the room.

Comment: Thank you!  However, I am still not able to add a comment to the chat room.

Comment: @FrankHubeny sorry about that. I thought just talking in it worked, apparentely you need to press the magic button as well. It should work now, please let me know if not

Comment: It is working now!